# When to use $this->$property

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

I am having trouble understanding when and why you need to use $this->$property. So adding the `$` to both the the `this` keyword and the `property`. I have only seen this used within the magic methods `__get()` and `__set()`. Can anybody elaborate?

Comment: Maybe when the property name is saved in a variable (e.g. `$var = "ThisIsMyProperty";`) then you use it like this: `$this->$var` ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$this->$property` when `$property` contains a name of a property or `$this->$function()` when `$function` contains a function name.

Example:

```
class MyClass {
    private $email = "rr@rr.com";

    public function getProperty($p){
        return $this->$p;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass;
$obj->getProperty("email"); // Returns rr@rr.com
```

Comment: Agree with @Richard Reiber

Comment: Ahh I see. So referencing the property/method? Thank you sir.

Comment: @JuanRangel: Yes. No problem. You can also see [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).